# Pass Object to Custom Annotation View

Tags: ios, swift, annotations

I have a Realm object `Place` with name, description, and coordinate objects. When the `mapView` is loaded, a pin is created for each instance of the Realm object. What I want to achieve is that when you click on the annotation of each pin you will come to a detail view giving you more information about the place. Is there a way to pass this Place object to the custom annotation so I can use its attributes in the `prepareForSegue` function and access and manipulate them in the `DetailViewController`?

Here's my `CustomAnnotation` class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit
import RealmSwift

class CustomAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var place = Place()
}
```

And here the functions in the `ViewController` with the `mapView`:

```
func loadLocations() {
        for place in realm.objects(Place) {
            let userLocationCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(place.latitude, place.longitude)
            let pinForUserLocation = CustomAnnotation()
            pinForUserLocation.coordinate = userLocationCoordinates
            pinForUserLocation.title = place.name
            pinForUserLocation.subtitle = place.placeDescription
            pinForUserLocation.place = place
            mapView.addAnnotation(pinForUserLocation)
            mapView.showAnnotations([pinForUserLocation], animated: true)
        }
    }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if !(annotation is CustomAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }
        let reuseId = "customAnnotation"
        var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        if view == nil {
            view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            view!.image = UIImage(named:"locationAnnotation")
            view!.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
            view!.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            view!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return view
    }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showPlaceDetailSegue", sender: annotation)
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showPlaceDetailSegue" {
            let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! PlaceDetailViewController
            vc.name = sender!.title
            vc.descriptionText = sender!.subtitle
            vc.coordinate = sender!.coordinate
            vc.place = sender!.place
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to annotation by `view.annotation` and cast it to your custom class in

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
let annotation = view.annotation as! CustomAnnotation
    performSegueWithIdentifier("showPlaceDetailSegue", sender: annotation)
}
```

Comment: It tells me "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments" when changing to `view = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)`. I guess I still have some errors in my CustomAnnotation class?

Comment: Awesome exactly what I needed! Thanks!